# Output ACF Flexible Content fields in a table (with the table header not to be repeated through loop)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I would like to make a table with flexible content fields.

There are two main issues

- If I insert table topic code outside the loop, the table header gets repeated for every single field (flexible content row).
- If I insert table topic code inside the loop, the data doesn't not get in the table properly. Only some fields of the first flexible content row were in the table. The rest flexible content rows didn't show up. (The table was empty except the first table row too.)

How to make a table with one header and get all the flexible content rows and their fields display correctly in a table form?

edited: below is the repeater field code. I have already moved to repeater field.

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'pokemon_level_up' ) ) : ?>

    <table>
        <caption>รายละเอียดท่า</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">เลเวล</th>
                    <th scope="col">ท่า</th>
                    <th scope="col">ชนิด</th>
                    <th scope="col">ประเภท</th>
                    <th scope="col">ความแรง</th>
                    <th scope="col">ความแม่นยำ</th>
                    <th scope="col">PP</th>
                    <th scope="col">% เอฟเฟกที่สอง</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

    <?php while ( have_rows( 'pokemon_level_up' ) ) : the_row(); ?>

        <?php $move_id = get_sub_field('pokemon_select_move'); ?>

                <tr>
                    <td data-label="เลเวล"><?php the_sub_field( 'pokemon_level' ); ?></td>
                    <td data-label="ท่า"><?php echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( $move_id ).'">'.get_the_title( $move_id ).'</a>'; ?></td>
                    <td data-label="ชนิด"><?php $move_type = get_field( 'move_type', $move_id ); ?>
                        <?php if ( $move_type ) { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $move_type['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $move_type['alt']; ?>" />
                        <?php } ?></td>
                    <td data-label="ประเภท"><?php $move_category = get_field( 'move_category', $move_id ); ?>
                        <?php if ( $move_category ) { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $move_category['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $move_category['alt']; ?>" />
                        <?php } ?></td>
                    <td data-label="ความแรง"><?php the_field( 'move_power', $move_id ); ?></td>
                    <td data-label="ความแม่นยำ"><?php the_field( 'move_accuracy', $move_id ); ?></td>
                    <td data-label="PP"><?php the_field( 'move_pp', $move_id ); ?></td>
                    <td data-label="% เอฟเฟกที่สอง"><?php the_field( 'move_secondary_effect', $move_id ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="8"><?php the_field( 'move_description', $move_id ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // no rows found ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the original table source code
https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MyqmdM

Actually, I could have used repeater fields instead. I have got an idea from this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRVslHJR9to

So, I went with flexible content instead of repeater fields.

Could you please help me fix the code? or Should I use repeater fields instead? (if it could do the same trick as taught in that particular YouTube video.)

Thanks!

Comment: If the only issue on ’topic outside loop’ is the repeated header you could just use a loop counter variable. Then display header only in the first loop.

Comment: Just noticed: put the endwhile before closing table tag, that should fix it

Comment: Simple but efficient!! It worked as you expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

All things will be repeated inside the while loop.

So, Keep your `<tbody>` outside the while loop. So in While loop there only `<tr>` and `<tr>` will repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have tried that before, but it didn't succeed. Only data from the first repeater row displayed correctly in table form. The rest rows did show up but they were outside the table.

Comment: Ok. Let me check once more Correctly.

Comment: Have you tried this. https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-field-inside-flexible-content/

Comment: Thanks for your kind effort to help me. I just needed to put endwhile before </table>

Comment: Yes. That I said you before.